How to create infinite image slider using Tailwind in Svelte?
I'm trying to create a following image slider in Svelte using Tailwind:

I have created a sample array:
    let carouselFilters = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Urban & Cityscape',
            img: '/images/references/02ltp444-broad-museum-michigan-15-.jpg',
            description: 'Architecture creating a Home for Art'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Museums & Culture',
            img: '/images/references/06_CFT540_P_CROXLEY_PARK_WATFORD_1_1200x800.jpg',
            description: 'Innovative Workspace Designs'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Landscape',
            img: '/images/references/06_CFT540_P_CROXLEY_PARK_WATFORD_1_1200x800.jpg',
            description: 'Landscape'
        },
    ];

and a variable and a function to change the state:
    let activeFilter = $state(1);

    function changeFilter(filter: number) {
        activeFilter = filter;
    }

I have already created the layout:
<div class="mt-20 px-16 w-full">
    <h3 class="border-none text-[2.25rem] font-bold">Discover our Solutions</h3>

    <div class="relative w-full">
        {#each carouselFilters as carousel}
            <div
                class="absolute inset-0 image h-[46rem] w-10/12 px-16 py-9 rounded-[1.875rem] transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 transform {carousel.id ===
                1
                    ? 'translate-x-0'
                    : 'translate-x-full ml-6'}"
                style:--background-image-url="url({carousel.img})"
            >
                <div class="w-1/2 text-white">
                    <p class="font-base">{carousel.name}</p>
                    <h3 class="border-none font-bold leading-none text-[2.25rem]">
                        {carousel.description}
                    </h3>
                    <a
                        href="/"
                        class="bg-[#EAEAEA] text-black max-w-max py-3 pl-5 pr-16 flex items-center gap-2.5 rounded-3xl mt-5"
                        >More<Arrow /></a
                    >
                </div>
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>

    <div class="mt-[47rem] flex items-center p-1 rounded-full bg-[#EAEAEA] max-w-max text-base">
        {#each carouselFilters as filter}
            <button
                class="cursor-pointer rounded-full py-2.5 px-8 transition-colors ease-in-out duration-300 {activeFilter ===
                filter.id
                    ? 'bg-black text-white'
                    : ''}"
                onclick={() => changeFilter(filter.id)}
            >
                {filter.name}
            </button>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>

In theory it should horizontally scroll, but it does not. I have tried it in snippet:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative w-full">
  <div class="absolute inset-0 image h-[46rem] w-10/12 px-16 py-9 rounded-[1.875rem] transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 transform" style="background-image: url('https://www.allplan.com/fileadmin/_processed_/2/4/csm_iStock-1133400370_NEU_7a3b1e8724.jpg'); background-size: cover;">
    <div class="w-1/2 text-white">
      <p class="font-base">Urban & Cityscape</p>
      <h3 class="border-none font-bold leading-none text-[2.25rem]">
        Architecture creating a Home for Art
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="absolute inset-0 image h-[46rem] w-10/12 px-16 py-9 rounded-[1.875rem] transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 transform ml-6 translate-x-full" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/800px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg'); background-size: cover;">
    <div class="w-1/2 text-white">
      <p class="font-base">Museums & Culture</p>
      <h3 class="border-none font-bold leading-none text-[2.25rem]">
        Innovative Workspace Designs
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Is there any other configuration I need to do in Svelte for this?
